# Get function name from text file base on line of code

Tags: c#, c++, text, static, analysis

I got a C++ source called 'MyCpp.cpp', it locates in: C:\MyCpp.cpp

```
...
5 string CplusplusWarningFunction()
6 {
7   int a = 69;
8   int b = a + 1;
9   a = b;
10  b = 69;
11  return "42 is the answer";
12 }
...
```

Now I want to write a C# function like this

```
void CodeAnalyzer()
{
    string path = @"C:\MyCpp.cpp";
    int line = 11;
    IEnumerable<string> loc = File.ReadLines(path);

    string code = loc.ElementAt(line-1);//Yes, it is 'return "42 is the answer";', good job!
    string functionFullName = "???";//This suppose to be the string 'CplusplusWarningFunction()', but How to do it???
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The code {0} at line {1} is in function {2}",code,line,functionFullName));
}
```

How can I get the function name to replace the string "???" in the C# code above?

I know this can be done because MS' FxCop can do it, sort of (FxCop analyzes the compiled object code, not the original source code). Well if compiled object code can be done, why not the original source code.

And Visual Studio can do it like the image below, I hope there is a way to access Visual Studio API:
[image]

Thank for reading.

Comment: loc.ElementAt(5) ? or 4 - not sure if it's zero-based when you call that

Comment: Parsing C++ is a *lot* harder than parsing C#.  (In fact, one of the design aims of C# was to create a regular language that is much easier for tools to parse.)  I really strongly suggest that you consider using something like the LLVM project to add hooks to add suitable hooks to the C++ compiler.  Also note that FxCop is a multi-man-year project - it is not something that a student can knock up in a couple of months.

Comment: @mmcrae I think the idea is that the OP wants this to work for different code files and for different line numbers.

Comment: Actually, I got a couple of ideals, you see, in Visual Studio, when you put your caret in the C++ source code, Visual Studio gives you the function name, I think there must be a way to get the function name just like Visual Studio did.

Comment: Or like Pvs studio viva64, maybe we can create a extension so we can access Visual Studio API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with a code like this, and it's quite good so far.

```
class CppFunction
{
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }
    public int StartLine { get; set; }
    public int EndLines { get; set; }
}

List<CppFunction> AnalyzeCpp(string path)
{
    List<CppFunction> lstCppFunc = new List<CppFunction>();

    IEnumerable<string> loc = File.ReadLines(path, encode);

    string[] locNoCom = RemoveComment(loc);
    RemoveIfdefineDebug(locNoCom);
    int level = 0;

    CppFunction crtFunc = null;
    int lineCount = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    bool startName = false;
    string builderToString;
    string lastLine = "";
    foreach (string line in locNoCom)
    {
        lineCount++;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            lastLine = line;
            continue;
        }

        if (level <= 0)
        {
            if (line.Contains('('))
            {
                crtFunc = new CppFunction();
                if (line.Trim().IndexOf('(') == 0)
                    builder.Append(lastLine);
                builder.AppendLine(line);
                crtFunc.StartLine = lineCount;
                startName = true;
            }
            if (startName)
            {
                builderToString = builder.ToString();
                if (line != builderToString.Replace("\r\n",string.Empty))
                    builder.AppendLine(line);
                if (line.Contains(')'))
                {
                    startName = false;
                    if (crtFunc != null)
                        crtFunc.FunctionName = builder.ToString();
                    builder.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        if(line.Contains('{'))
        {
            foreach(char c in line)
            {
                if (c == '{')
                    level++;
            }
        }
        if(line.Contains('}'))
        {
            foreach (char c in line)
            {
                if (c == '}')
                    level--;
            }
            if (crtFunc != null && level <= 0)
            {
                crtFunc.EndLines = lineCount;
                lstCppFunc.Add(crtFunc);
                crtFunc = null;
                level = 0;
            }
        }
        lastLine = line;
    }

    return lstCppFunc;
}
```

Now we have the list of Function and its start line, end line, when we got the line of code, we can check if it is in between which function, and BAM - we got the function line.

Edit:
We also need to remove comment to increase the righteousness

```
string[] RemoveComment(IEnumerable<string> loc)
{
    string[] line = loc.ToArray();
    bool startComment = false;
    int startComPos=0;
    int endComPos=-1;
    int count = line.Length;
    string comment;

    bool mistakeComment;

    int multiCommentStart, multiCommentEnd;

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[i]))
            continue;
        if (line[i].Contains("//"))
        {
            mistakeComment = false;
            if(line[i].Contains("*//*"))//Case mistake /**//**/ with //
            {
                if ((line[i].IndexOf("//") - line[i].IndexOf("*//*")) == 1)
                {
                    mistakeComment = true;
                }
            }

            if(!mistakeComment)
            {
                comment = line[i].Substring(line[i].IndexOf("//"));
                line[i] = line[i].Replace(comment, string.Empty);
            }
        }
        if(line[i].Contains("/*"))
        {
            startComment = true;
            startComPos = line[i].IndexOf("/*");
            endComPos = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            startComPos = 0;
        }

        if (startComment)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line[i]))
            {
                if (line[i].Contains("*/"))
                {
                    startComment = false;
                    endComPos = line[i].IndexOf("*/", startComPos);
                }
                else
                    endComPos = -1;
                if (endComPos == -1)
                {
                    comment = line[i].Substring(startComPos);
                    line[i] = line[i].Replace(comment, string.Empty);
                }
                else
                {
                    comment = line[i].Substring(startComPos, endComPos - startComPos + 2);
                    line[i] = line[i].Replace(comment, string.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        if (line[i].Contains("/*"))
        while((multiCommentStart = line[i].IndexOf("/*")) >= 0 &&
            (multiCommentEnd = line[i].IndexOf("*/")) >= 0 &&
            multiCommentEnd > multiCommentStart)
        {
            comment = line[i].Substring(multiCommentStart, multiCommentEnd - multiCommentStart + 2);
            line[i] = line[i].Replace(comment, string.Empty);
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

Oh, and we also need to remove the Debug code also

```
void RemoveIfdefineDebug(string[] linesCode)
{
    bool startRemove = false;
    for(int i=0;i<linesCode.Length;i++)
    {
        if(startRemove)
        {
            if (linesCode[i].Contains("#endif"))
            {
                startRemove = false;
            }
            else
                linesCode[i] = string.Empty;
        }
        if (linesCode[i].Contains("#ifdef "))
        {
            startRemove = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And Finally, the main function

```
string GetCodeAndFunctionName(string path, int line)
{
    List<CppFunction> lstCppFunc = AnalyzeCpp(path);
    foreach(CppFunction func in lstCppFunc)
    {
        if(func.EndLines >= line && func.StartLine <= line)
        {
            return func.FunctionName;
        }
    }
    return "x";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is only one function, for each line you could try

```
//do this in a foreach loop that will iterate through every line
string functionName;
if (line.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Contains("()") && !x.Contains(".")).Count() > 0)
{
    functionName = line.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Contains("()") && !x.Contains(".")).First();
}
```

Now this will work on your example code, but this is also is *very* rudimentary and I'm sure there are a lot of cases where this wouldn't work. This might not be a bad starting point though.